# Yii: How to use videos, upload them and managing them

Tags: php, yii

Any way to upload and manage videos in yii, i have posted this question quite times but no one responds to it. I have used and tried `multiuploadfiles`. The video gets load in the video directory but doesn't comes in the manage section, so please anyone who has idea how to upload and manage videos in yii please share how to do it. Thank you.

Comment: Your question have to many possible answers. Decompose it.

Comment: I just want that the admin can create a video via this url:localhost/projectname/video/create and the video gets uploaded in the video directory, and when the admin types this url:localhost/projectname/video/manage, the admin can see the uploaded videos here and can manage these videos according to it's need.

Comment: Please share if you have a solution how to do this, and which code should i share here, thank you..!!